# How can I set Google API Key programmatically? I'm getting "The request is missing a valid API key." Error (403)

Tags: .net, google-api, labview, google-translation-api

I am accessing the .NET DLL in LabVIEW for the google translation API (Google.Cloud.Translation.V2.dll), and tried to set the "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" via the command prompt as shown in Google's example on how to set everything up to get the translate API working. It does not seem to work and when I run my code, I get a "missing a valid API key" error (403). I think I need to set the key programmatically but I cannot find any documentation or examples anywhere on how to set the API Key programmatically. Below is the .NET error I received when trying to translate some German text to English.

```
Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The request is missing a valid API key. [403]
Errors [
Message[The request is missing a valid API key.] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
]
```

Do I need access to a different DLL to set the API Key? I downloaded all of these (because they were dependencies and I wasn't sure what all I needed when accessing the Google API in LabVIEW) and have looked through potential methods I could use in all of them. These are them:

Google.Cloud.Translation.V2.dll, Google.Apis.Translate.v2.dll, Google.Api.Gax.dll, Google.Api.Gax.Rest.dll, Google.Apis.Auth.dll, Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices.dll, Google.Apis.Core.dll, Google.Apis.dll, Google.Apis.PlatformServices.dll, Newtonsoft.Json.dll, System.Interactive.Async.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished setting the "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" system environment variable in C# with the following code:

```
string keyFilepath = @"JSON\Key\FilePath\Here";
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", keyFilepath);
```

I accomplished this same code in LabVIEW with the following code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaKBY.jpg

The second window shows the selected .NET constant being passed into the first invoke node. Create a constant reference passed into the invoke node, right click and select class, browse to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ and select your latest version of Framework on your PC, and dive into mscorlib.

I accomplished the German Translation with the following LabVIEW code, the right window being the selected .NET constant being passed into the first invoke node.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lufVu.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there are too many users who have used these dlls from LabVIEW, best I can suggest is to find a clean .net example and determine the steps from that to reproduce the api call.  That is if you can even construct the needed assemblies in LabVIEW, since you can't always do that with .net APIs depending on objects and data types it needs, it can be hard to match things up sometimes.  I've done lots of .net work, but never with google APIs, but usually find solutions just by replicating first what works with .net natively.

Comment: Right. I've been struggling to find a clean .net example, and that's been my problem, because Google explains that you need to set the API Key in powershell or the command prompt in their explanation here in their "Before you begin #2":

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#using_the_client_library 

I was able to create a service object and am right on the verge of being able to translate some text, I just can't properly set the API key for some reason. I'm specifically looking for an example that sets the API key programmatically so I can do that.

Thanks